# How to find the vertices of a triangle formed from 3 vector lines

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Can someone help me find the answer to this question?

> Three lines which form a triangle have vector equations:
> $$r=16i-4j-6k+\lambda(-12i+4j+3k)$$
> $$r=16i+28j+15k+\mu(8i+8j+5k)$$
> $$r=i+9j+3k+v(4i-12j-8k)$$
> Find the position vector of each of the three vertices of the triangle, given that the triangle formed is an acute angled triangle.

Can anybody tell me what the answer for the three position vectors are?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I expressed each equation in parametric form and equated them three times to find the three vertices. I don't need someone to right the whole answer out on here just if they could let me know what the answer is.

Comment: My answers for the position vectors are $\begin{pmatrix} 40 \\ 52 \\ 30 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 44 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have found the three vertices, in order to check the result, let plug the pair of values you have found for $\lambda$, $\mu$ and $\nu$ in the corresponding pair of equations.

As an alternative quick check the direction vector for any pair of vertices should be parallel to the direcion vector of the line passing through them.

Comment: I understand how to do it, and I think I have the correct answer, it's just my exercise book gives me a different answer which is why I want to know if my answer is the correct answer. My answers are $\begin{pmatrix} -40 \\ 52 \\ 30 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 44 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$ Can you find out the answer and let  me know if mine are correct?

Comment: There is some problem with your solution. For example $$\begin{pmatrix} -40 \\ 52 \\ 30 \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 44 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -40 \\ 8 \\ 25 \end{pmatrix}$$ which is not parallel to any direction vectors. I suggest to add your solution and your book solution in your question.

Comment: I don;t understand why you subtracted two of the vectors/vertices. Could you explain?

Comment: Given two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ the vector $P_2-P_1$ is the direction vector for the line passing through $P_1$ and $P_2$. What is the solution given in the book?

Comment: The solutions in my book for the vertices are $\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} -8 \\ 4 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 12 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @mikejacob You see in this case we obtain  $$\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} -8 \\ 4 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ -4 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$$ which is the direction vector for the first line. You can easily check for the others. This is not a proof for correct answers but can help to exclude wrong answers.

Comment: But what are we trying to find when we subtract two of the vectors? Because to my knowledge, when you subtract two position vectors you find the vector that takes you from one of the points to another. $\overrightarrow{0B}-\overrightarrow{OA}=\overrightarrow{AB}$

Comment: Exactly and these vectors must be aligned with the direction vectors of the lines/sides.

Comment: Oh i see, that makes a lot of sense. Wait so are both the answers wrong?

Comment: The solution given in the book seems to be correct since it passes this check. To be sure we need to check that these points belong to the corresponding lines. Your solution is certainly wrong because it doesn’t pass the check.

Comment: Brilliant, I understand this now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mikejacob You are welcome! It's really my plesure can help student well motivated like you. I suggest to add also your solutions and book solutions in your question in order to make it more complete and clear. Bye